# Renaming series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with series, and I was wondering how I can rename the series when writing to a file. For example, my output csv consists of the following:

```
Gene_Name,0
A2ML1,15
AAK1,8
```

I want it to be the following:

```
Gene_Name,Count
A2ML1,15
AAK1,8
```

Note: I don't want my header to be "Gene_Name,0" but "Gene_Name,Count." How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using Series or DataFrame?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make "Count" the name of your series, just set it with `your_series.name = "Count"` and then call to_csv like this: `your_series.to_csv("c:\\output.csv", header=True, index_label="Gene_Name")`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it:

```
s.to_frame("Count").to_csv("output.csv", header=True, index_label="Gene_Name")
```

or

```
s.reset_index(name="Count").to_csv("output.csv", header=True, index_label="Gene_Name")
```